# Removing last row from appending CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I would like to remove the last row appended to a CSV file (sort of like 'undo' last appended row).  So far I have an interface that takes a user-generated raw_input and performs a command.  For instance, 'a' adds the row to the CSV file, 'r' rejects the row from the CSV file.  I would like 'u' to remove the last row added to the CSV file.  My code looks like this

```
for i in range(0,len(out['bestObjID']),1):
    j = raw_input('\n Add (a) or Reject (r)?: ')
    if j=='ADD' or j=='add' or j=='a' or j=='A':
        c = csv.writer(open('NLS1_candidates.csv','a+'))
        c.writerow(out[i])
        print(' Writing object to candidate list...')
        i += 1
    elif j=='REJECT' or j=='reject' or j=='r' or j=='R':
        print(' Object rejected...')
        i += 1
    elif j=='UNDO' or j=='undo' or j=='u' or j=='U':
        i -= 1
    elif j=='?' or j=='h' or j=='help' or j=='HELP' or j=='H':
        print('    \n Press (a) to add object to candidate list')
        print('     Press (r) to add to reject object')
        print('     Press (?) or (h) for help')
        print('     Press (q) to Quit')
    elif j=='q' or j=='Q' or j=='QUIT' or j=='quit':
        print('\n Quitting...')
        break
    else:
        print('    \n Press (a) to add object to candidate list')
        print('     Press (r) to add to reject object')
        print('     Press (?) or (h) for help')
        print('     Press (q) to Quit')
```

How would I go about adding 'undo' functionality to my CSV file?

Edit: I've failed to mention that when I add a row to the CSV file, `out[i]` is a row read from another CSV file.  If that helps at all.

Comment: Does your code currently add rows correctly?

Comment: Yes, my code does append rows correctly (at least the way I want it to)

Comment: Just to clarify, do you just want to undo an operation from the same run of the program (you could store the position of the last line written and truncate there) or always remove the last line even if you haven't added a line in this run of the program?

Answer (score 1):

If your file is not large, you can store them in a list by `readlines()` and remove the last row, and then write to the file with the same filename.

```
cat sample.csv                                                                                                                                                                    
line1
line2
line3
cat test.py                                                                                                                                                                       
inputs = open("sample.csv")
all_lines = inputs.readlines()
all_lines.pop(len(all_lines)-1)  # removes last line
inputs.close()  # closes file

# truncate file and write all lines except the last line
with open("sample.csv", "w") as out:
    for line in all_lines:
        out.write(line.strip() + "\n")

python test.py                                                                                                                                                                    
cat sample.csv                                                                                                                                                                    
line1
line2
```

Comment: My CSV file is, unfortunately, very large.

Comment: in your case, database might be a better choice

Answer (score 0):

A (dirty) solution can be to write each line by specifing the EOF character (`\n` probably) at the beginning,
and, when the last line should be deleted, to write the [`\r` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return).

But this don't handle multiple line deletion.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a very large file, a solution is to define a `NB_UNDO_LIMIT` integer, which is equal to the number of lines saved in memory before writing, allowing the user to undo at most `NB_UNDO_LIMIT` times the addition.

```
from collections import deque

NB_UNDO_LIMIT = 10
output = open('output', 'w')

float_lines = deque(maxlen=NB_UNDO_LIMIT)
for line in open('filename'):
    # write the older line if necessary
    if len(float_lines) == NB_UNDO_LIMIT:
        output.write(float_lines.popLeft())
    float_lines.append(line)
    # do a job on the NB_UNDO_LIMIT last lines
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is untested, but should give you a basic idea of how it could be done. *One* of the reasons I asked whether your current code works was because of the manual manipulation of the `i` variable inside the `for i in range(...):` loop. Seems like it could cause problems...

```
last_write = None

for i in range(0,len(out['bestObjID']),1):
    j = raw_input('\n Add (a) or Reject (r)?: ')
    if j=='ADD' or j=='add' or j=='a' or j=='A':
        with open('NLS1_candidates.csv', 'ab+') as f:
            f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
            last_write = f.tell()  # remember where added row starts
            c = csv.writer(f)
            print(' Writing object to candidate list...')
            c.writerow(out[i])
    elif j=='REJECT' or j=='reject' or j=='r' or j=='R':
        print(' Object rejected...')
        i += 1
    elif j=='UNDO' or j=='undo' or j=='u' or j=='U':
        if last_write is None:
            print(' Nothing to undo!')
        else:
            with open('NLS1_candidates.csv', 'ab+') as f:
                f.seek(last_write)  # go back to where last row started
                print(' Removing last row added.')
                f.truncate()  # reset file size back to that point
                last_write = None
                i -= 1
    elif j=='?' or j=='h' or j=='help' or j=='HELP' or j=='H':
        print('    \n Press (a) to add object to candidate list')
        print('     Press (r) to add to reject object')
        print('     Press (?) or (h) for help')
        print('     Press (q) to Quit')
    elif j=='q' or j=='Q' or j=='QUIT' or j=='quit':
        print('\n Quitting...')
        break
    else:
        print('    \n Press (a) to add object to candidate list')
        print('     Press (r) to add to reject object')
        print('     Press (?) or (h) for help')
        print('     Press (q) to Quit')
```

Comment: I like your answer except that has to be `f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)` (seek zero bytes from the end of the file) and can't seek/tell be dodgy on text mode files because of newline handling?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake, I'll fix it. According to the documentation it might not even be necessary to seek to the end when a file is opened in append mode. You should be opening your csv files in binary mode (as per all the [examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) in the documentation), so using `seek`/`tell` should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

*This will work only when you do not have successive UNDOs.

If you make some changes to file.csv, then the previous copy of that would be stored in file.csv~
Just do a file replace to get back the previous content.

Comment: OP doesn't keep an old copy of the csv. This might work for a text editor that does keep that last version of a file, but not for this code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `wfgeo`: another and I guess a simple solition is to use `os` library, find the last row and truncate it:

```
import csv
import os

with open(fileName, 'w', newline='') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', dialect='excel')
  
  for row in rows:
    row = rows[0].values()
    writer.writerow(row)

  f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
  f.seek(f.tell()-2, os.SEEK_SET)
  f.truncate()
```